spl-token create-token error
When running the command spl-token create-token I receive this error:
Creating token BkXycn3YtU48HYPhUmWz8XnycQ8XjrV3GTHwZCiuP6EQ under program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(AccountNotFound), logs: Some([]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) })


The error message Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit means that you didn't have any SOL to fund the creation of your tokens.
Run solana address to get your address to fund, and run solana config get to make sure you're on the correct cluster. You can change your cluster with solana config set -um if you want to be on mainnet.

thanks for the help, would you happen to know to total SOL cost to create my token on the mainnet as i cant find the answer anywhere?

Ask as a separate question and we'll get it answered
